# Changes in hook__civicrm_alterMailParams not respected anymore when sending mails to individual contacts

Tags: civimail, hooks, core

In our development environment I redirect mails following some specific rules. I am quite sure that I achieved that in the past with `hook__civicrm_alterMailParams` where I changed the `$params['toEmail']` to whatever email suited. Additionally I changed `$params['text']`to have some info about the original email address.

Now this logic starts to fail after upgrading from CiviCRM 5.50.0 to 5.50.2 (when you send a mail to an individual contact from the contact view page). The reason is that `$params['toEmail]` has now the value `NULL` instead of a string with the email address. For sending mass mailings this logic still works - for every single email the hook is called with an $params array with 'toEmail' set.

The release notes from 5.50.1 and 5.50.2 did not show any code changes that seem to be related to that. How can I find someone to check that? It seems to be a main issue to me when changes like that are made in core without any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook_civicrm_alterMailParams(&$params, $context) hook is called twice

1. $context == 'messageTemplate' -> When building the message, at this moment the toEmail is not set
2. $context == 'singleEmail' -> called when email is build and about to send.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you so much... I simply forgot about that and made a change in my own code that did not respect that fact. Sorry for the noise!